# Calculating Date from month and year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains two columns, `expMonth` and `expYear`. I need to `SELECT *` where the date is older than `NOW()`. My problem is, I don't even know how to approach this issue in **SQL** because I only have a month and year. Also, I would need to find the max amount of days for the given month and then based on that, piece together the information to create a date and then compare that date to `NOW()`. From what I have seen online, you can't really create a date in **SQL** from just having a month and year.

Example:

```
expMonth = 09 , expYear = 16.
findNumberOfDays(expMonth)
createDate(numberOfDaysforMonth,expMonth,expYear)`

SELECT * FROM Stacks WHERE createDate < NOW();
```

That was just some logical/pseudo code.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: I would consider devoting that energy to combining those columns into a new one, ditching the old two. Then enjoy some baked in functionality and high performance

Comment: Drew , I would love to if I had any control over this, but unfortunately, my team is stuck with that bad db design.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

```
where str_to_date(concat(exp_year, '-', expmonth), '%Y-%m') < now()
```

MySQL can handle partial dates. But, if you really want, you could use

```
str_to_date(concat(exp_year, '-', expmonth, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') < now()
```

if you think that is clearer.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, correct me if I am mistaken, but that only checks the month and year, not day as well. How do I incorporate the day in that function?

Comment: @user1830833 . . . MySQL can handle partial dates.  But, if you really want, you could use `str_to_date(concat(exp_year, '-', expmonth, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') < now()` if you think that is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

where str_to_date(concat(exp_year, '-', expmonth), '%Y-%m-01') < now()

If you need the date to be the last day of the month:

where last_day(str_to_date(concat(exp_year, '-', expmonth), '%Y-%m-01')) < now()